# OpenGL:How to make a "Polyman's" mouth open

Tags: c++, opengl, translation, polygon

I'm writing a program that has a polygon "man" walk from one side of the screen to the middle, open his mouth, jump up and do a flip, land, close his mouth, and walk left off the screen. I am a bit confused on how to make the lad's mouth open. I was thinking I could create a triangle of appropriate size the same color as the background and slowly translate it to where his mouth would be. What steps would I need to go through to make this possible, and where would I put the code to do so?

```
    #include<Windows.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<gl/glut.h>

using namespace std;

//***********************GLOBAL VALUES*********************************************

float theta=00.0; //global angular value for rotation
float scale1=1.0; //global scaling value
float dx=7.0,dy=-3.0;
int frame = 1;

void init(void); //This is a function to initialize the window clear color
void RenderScene(void); //This a function to draw polyman in an opened window
void loadicon(float[],float[],float[],float[], float[], float[]); //Load the polyman icon
void drawicon(float[],float[],float[],float[], float[], float[]); //Draw the icon the two first float for the square and the others for the line
void settrans(float[][3],float,float,float); //Sets the transformation matrix for desired scale, rotation, new pos
float xprime(float,float,float[][3]); //Calculates x' from x and transform
float yprime(float,float,float[][3]); //Calculates y' from y and transform
void transform(float[],float[],float[],float[], float[], float[], float[][3],float[],float[],float[],float[], float[], float[]); //performs the transformation on the icon pattern  
void myidle(void);
void SetupRC(void); //Sets up the clear color
void TimerFunction(int); //This call back function is called each 30ms and changes the location, scale and rotation

//***********************MAIN PROGRAM**********************************************

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Set up window title
    char header[]="Polyman's journey";
    glutInit(&argc,argv);

    //Set up the display mode with two buffers and RGB colors
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);

    //Initialize window size and position
    glutInitWindowSize(560,440);
    glutInitWindowPosition(140,20);

    //Initialize background color of the window
    SetupRC();

    //Open and label window
    glutCreateWindow(header);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    glutTimerFunc(30,TimerFunction, 1); //Call the TimerFunction each 30s

    //Now draw the scene
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

//*************************RenderScene Function*************************************

void RenderScene(void)
{
    float xdel=0.25;
    float px[7],py[7],plx[4],ply[4], pl2x[4], pl2y[4];// These variables hold the pattern for the icon square plus line
    float pxp[7],pyp[7],plxp[4],plyp[4], pl2xp[4], pl2yp[4],t[3][3]; //These varables hold the pattern after transformation, t is the transformation matrix

    //clear the window with the current background color
    cout<<"in RenderScene"<<endl;

    //set the current drawing color to white
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //set the viewport to the window dimensions
    glViewport(0,0,560,440);

    //Establish the clipping volumn in user units, first clear all the translation matrices
    glOrtho(-7.0,7.0,-7.0,7.0,1.0,-1.0);
    loadicon(px,py,plx,ply, pl2x, pl2y);

    //draw the icon untransformed
    settrans(t,scale1,dx,dy);
    transform(pxp,pyp,plxp,plyp,pl2xp,pl2yp, t,px,py,plx,ply, pl2x, pl2y);

    //clear the window with the background color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //set the current drawing color to white
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);

    //now draw the figure
    drawicon(pxp,pyp,plxp,plyp,pl2xp, pl2yp);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    return;
}//end of render scene

//************************LOAD ICON FUNCTION***********************************

void loadicon(float px[],float py[],float plx[],float ply[],float pl2x[],float pl2y[]) //Loads the polyman
{
    //Set the coordinates of the square
    px[0]=-0.625   ;    py[0]=0.625      ;
    px[1]=0.625    ;    py[1]=0.625      ;
    px[2]=1.0      ;    py[2]=0.0        ;
    px[3]=0.625    ;    py[3]=-0.625     ;
    px[4]=-0.625   ;    py[4]=-0.625     ;
    px[5]= -1.0    ;    py[5]= 0.0       ;
    px[6]=-0.625   ;    py[6]=0.625      ;

    //set the right foot
    plx[0]=  0.25   ;    ply[0]= -0.625    ;
    plx[1]= 0.25    ;    ply[1]= -0.875    ;
    plx[2]= 0.0    ;    ply[2]= -0.875   ;
    plx[3] = 0.25 ;     ply[3] = -0.875;

    //set the left foot
    pl2x[0]= -0.125 ;    pl2y[0]= -0.375   ;
    pl2x[1]= -0.125 ;    pl2y[1]= -0.875   ;
    pl2x[2]= -0.375 ;    pl2y[2]= -0.875   ;
    pl2x[3]= -0.125 ;    pl2y[3]= -0.875   ;
    return;
} //end of loadicon

//************************FUNCTION DRAWICON***********************************

void drawicon(float pxp[],float pyp[],float plxp[],float plyp[], float pl2xp[], float pl2yp[])
{
    //draw the square icon at the transformed position

    int i;
    cout<<"in drawicon"<<endl;
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

    //move to first point in the icon
    glVertex2f(pxp[0],pyp[0]);

    //now draw the rest of the box
    for(i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        glVertex2f(pxp[i],pyp[i]);
    }
    glEnd();

    //now draw the line
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(plxp[0],plyp[0]);
    for (i=1; i <=3; i++)
        {
            glVertex2f(plxp[i],plyp[i]);
        }//glVertex2f(plxp[2],plyp[2]);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(pl2xp[0], pl2yp[0]);
    for (i=1; i <=3; i++)
    {
        glVertex2f(pl2xp[i], pl2yp[i]);
    }
    glEnd();

    //now fill the rectangle which is made by half of the square

    //set the shading color to green
    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);

    //redraw the polygon
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    //Firts point is where the line intersects the top of the square
    glVertex2f(pxp[0], pyp[0]);
    //rigth corner upper
    glVertex2f(pxp[1],pyp[1]);
    //right corner lower
    glVertex2f(pxp[2],pyp[2]);
    //left intersect
    glVertex2f(pxp[3],pyp[3]);
    glVertex2f(pxp[4],pyp[4]);
    glVertex2f(pxp[5],pyp[5]);
    glVertex2f(pxp[6],pyp[6]);
    return;
} //end of draw icon

//************************FUNCTION SETTRANS***********************************

void settrans(float t[][3],float scale1,float dx,float dy)
{
    cout<<"in settrans"<<endl;
    int i,j;
    float ts,ct,st;
    double theta1;

    //setup identity matrix
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
        {
            t[i][j]=0.0;
            if(i==j) t[i][j]=1.0; 
        }
    }

    //set scale parameters
    if(scale1!=-9.0)
    {
        t[0][0]=scale1;
        t[1][1]=scale1;
    }
    if(theta!=-9.0)
    {
        theta1=(3.1416/180.0)*theta;
        ct=cos(theta1);
        st=sin(theta1);
        ts=t[0][0];
        t[0][0]=ts*ct;
        t[0][1]=ts*st;
        ts=t[1][1];
        t[1][0]=-ts*st;
        t[1][1]=ts*ct;
    }

    //translate the figure

    if((dx+dy) != -18.0)
    {
        t[2][0]=dx;
        t[2][1]=dy;
    }
    return;
}//end of settrans

//************************FUNCTION XPRIME***********************************

float xprime(float x1,float y1, float t[][3])
{
    //this function pultiples the x vector by the transformation matrix
    float xp1;
    xp1=x1*t[0][0]+y1*t[1][0]+t[2][0];
    return xp1;
}

//************************FUNCTION YPRIME***********************************

float yprime(float x1,float y1, float t[][3])
{
    //this function pultiples the y vector by the transformation matrix
    float yp1;
    yp1=x1*t[0][1]+y1*t[1][1]+t[2][1];
    return yp1;
}

//************************FUNCTION TRANSFORM***********************************

void transform(float pxp[],float pyp[],float plxp[],float plyp[],float pl2xp[],float pl2yp[],float t[][3],float px[],float py[],float plx[],float ply[], float pl2x[], float pl2y[])
{
    int i;
    cout<<"in transform"<<endl;

    //transform the figure
    for(i=0;i<=6;i++)
    {
        pxp[i] = xprime(px[i],py[i],t);
        pyp[i] = yprime(px[i],py[i],t);
    }

    //transform the line
    for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        plxp[i] = xprime(plx[i],ply[i],t);
        plyp[i] = yprime(plx[i],ply[i],t);
    }

    for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        pl2xp[i] = xprime(pl2x[i],pl2y[i],t);
        pl2yp[i] = yprime(pl2x[i],pl2y[i],t);
    }
    return;
}//end of transform

//************************ FUNCTION SetupRC***********************************

void SetupRC(void)
{
    //sets the clear color of an open window and clears the open window
    //set clear color to green
    glClearColor(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
    return;
}//end of setupRC

//************************ FUNCTION Timer***********************************

void TimerFunction(int value)
{
    //this call back function is called each 30ms and changes the location, scale and rotation 
    static float swc=0.1,sdx=0.1,sdy=0.1;
    switch(frame)
    {
        case 1:
            //theta+=5.0;
            dx-=0.15;
            if(dx<=0.0)
            {
                dx=0.0;
                frame=2;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            dy+=0.2;
            if(dy>5.0)
            {
                dy=5.0;
                frame=3;
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            theta+=5.0;

            if(theta>360.0)
            {
                frame=4;
                theta=0.0;
                scale1=1.0;
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            dy-=0.2;
            if(dy<=-3.0)
            {
                dy=-3.0;
                frame=5;
            }
            break;

        case 5:
            dx-=0.15;
            //theta+=5.0;
            if(dx<=-8.0) dx=-8.0;
            break;
    }

    //redraw the scene with new coordinate
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(33,TimerFunction,1);
}
```

Also, we aren't allowed to use any of the built in translate, rotate, or scale functions that OpenGL provides since it's our first assignment. Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: your timer function is called every 30ms, you could try moving the triangle in that.

Comment: So in theory, I could build a new triangle, and then make a new case, and slowly translate the triangle in the new case just before he flips?

Comment: yes, or you could write your own transform function

Comment: Would I have to create a new loadTriangle, drawTriangle, etc etc? Or is there a simpler way? I'm sure there's an easier way, but also if there is where would I put it in my code?

Comment: That I can't really tell you. I'm guessing this is part of your homework assignment due to the wording of your question. As such, there are certain things your professor wants you to learn and certain ways that build up into more lessons. Experiment and see what works and what doesnt, and dont be afraid to ask your professor if you get stuck

Comment: you can't tell me because you don't know or because you want me to figure it out; My professor flies in from California to teach, he isn't ever on campus for me to ask questions

Comment: Well, thankfully there are ways you can contact him without him being in your presence :)
As for the initial query, I don't know how your professor wants you to do it and I want you to figure that out. Narrow down what you don't understand and do some research. As it stands, this question is a little vague and borderlines on "do my homework for me", which is why it ahs received so little attention. If you can find out exactly what you don't understand, itll benefit you and your question

Comment: I understand how to create a triangle, I understand how to shade in a triangle to the background color, I understand how to translate my triangle to where it needs to be,but I don't understand when I try to draw the triangle nothing comes up no matter where I put it.